# org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for custom object type

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-jpa

Spring boot 2.3

Entity `Cart` has many entites `CartItem`.

So here my models:

```
@Entity
public class Cart {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<CartItem> cartItems;


@Entity
public class CartItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private Product product;
    private int quantity;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id", nullable = false)
    private Cart cart;


@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    @ElementCollection
    private Set<String> images;
```

But when I run application I get error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cartRepository' defined in com.myproject.eshop_orders.repo.CartRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.myproject.eshop_orders.api.model.Product, at table: cart_item, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(product)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Product` in `CartItem` without defining any relation like `@OneToOne`. So JPA treats `product` as column in `CartItem` table  and can not determine compatible type for `product` for database column. That's why error states that

```
Could not determine type for: com.myproject.eshop_orders.api.model.Product, 
at table: cart_item, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(product)
```

May be you have `@OneToOne` relation with `Product` in `CartItem` table.

```
@OneToOne
private Product product;
```

Comment: So do you mean if I declare property of custom type, then I must use annotation @ OneToMany, @ ManyToOne and so on ?

Comment: Not actually, if  you use any custom type not compatible with database then you have to use AttributeConverter for this column 
Details: https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/

Comment: Also I think that I need to add this for Product's property:  @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id")